# Correcting a question

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I heard a lot of people saying this phrase repeatedly **'Where is the human rights'**

To me it sounds wrong.

Does anyone think it's wrong the way I think? Could you correct it in case you think it's wrong?

Comment: Which people? Native English speakers? What was the context? How do you think it's wrong? The question as written is unclear and incomplete.

Comment: Which refugees, in which country? Are they native speakers of English. How do you think they are wrong?

Answer (score 3):

This is an example where the people voicing their protest are taking a common English phrase, "Where is the X?" and modifying it for a new purpose.  "Where is the X?" when spoken with a note of indignation, implies that X *should* exist, but currently does not.

> **Where is the justice** for those young men killed by those police officers?!
>
> **Where is the democracy** when corporations and wealthy individuals can "donate" billions to election campaigns?!
>
> **Where is the gender equality**, when we have yet to elect a woman president?!

And so on.

In a similar way, "Where is the human rights?!" is not *intended* to be grammatical.  Rather it's meant to fit the same kind of structure as the above examples.

Side note:  "Human rights" can refer to multiple rights, or it can be a singular *compound noun*.  Often it will be capitalized when used as a compound noun.

> Numerous human rights **have** been violated since the coup
>
> Human Rights **is** the first topic on the agenda

Comment: Ok thank you very much for the answer. 
Are you a native English speaker or an English teacher? 
You're from america so I assume that you speak English as a first language. Right?

Comment: @Manzimes [Don't focus too much on whether someone is a native speaker](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/904/requests-for-native-speakers-to-answer-questions).

Answer (score 0):

"**[Human rights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_rights)**" is a plural subject so a plural verb is required. When you speak about human rights in general you don't place a definite article.

- Where are human rights?

However, "**where**" sounds rather odd and would depend on what you infer by using it.

You place "**the**" before "**human rights**" when you are referring to some specific human right. ([**UNIVERSAL DECLARATION OF HUMAN RIGHTS**](http://www.youthforhumanrights.org/what-are-human-rights/universal-declaration-of-human-rights/articles-1-15.html))

Comment: Er.  Not really.  While there are certainly multiple rights included in the scope of "human rights", the phrase is actually a singular topic, similar to how you would not say, "Mathematics **aren't** my favorite subject at school."   This doesn't mean "Where is the human rights" is correct either.  That's more like deliberately incorrect slogan grammar.

Comment: On further thought, there are circumstances where it can be plural, for example "numerous human rights **have** been abrogated since the coup".  But it's also a singular, e.g. "Human Rights in Africa **is** the first topic on the agenda"

Comment: Ok now that means it's quite common slogan to be used in that way although is sounds incorrect grammatically? Right?